# Azure App service with user-assigned managed identity cannot communicate with Azure App Configuration service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-configuration

I am trying to use Azure App Configuration service from Azure Web App (Linux) using user-assigned managed identity but application crashes at start-up. My web application is built using AspNet Core 3.1.

This is the code I used in Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                    {
                        var settings = config.Build();
                        var aacEndpoint = settings.GetSection("AzureAppConfig:Endpoint").Value;
                        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(acfg =>
                        {
                            acfg.Connect(new Uri(aacEndpoint), new ManagedIdentityCredential("<ClientId of MI>"));
                            var projectkeysFilter = "VSSP.Web/*";
                            var projectTrimKeyPrefix = "VSSP.Web/";
                            acfg.Select(projectkeysFilter, LabelFilter.Null);
                            acfg.TrimKeyPrefix(projectTrimKeyPrefix);
                        });
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

I have these configuration settings on Azure App Service:

> AZURE_CLIENT_ID: `<<xxClientId of MI>>`
>
> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: DEV

User assigned managed identity is provisioned in azure web app and granted *App Configuration Data Reader* role in App Configuration service.

Endpoint configured in appsettings.json

```
"AzureAppConfig": {
    "Endpoint": "https://app-zcfg-dev.azconfig.io"
  }
```

Comment: "application crashes at start-up" Is there some sort of exception?

Comment: No exception. This page is loaded  : ( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.